# Atlassian Jira: best practice for declined stories?

Tags: jira, scrum, backlog

What's the best way to keep declined stories? We don't want to delete them, to prevent that they are created again. So when you search for it you still find the story, but you know it's declined.

Currently we tag a declined story and set the status do "done", so it's removed from the backlog. But this solution is not very good, because in the search you don't see the tags and the story seems to be "done".

Do you have any better suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (Unfortunately, this question is too old to be  migrated.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customise JIRA to change the workflow of the user story "or other issue type" to include "Declined" status which is different than "Done". To do that

1. go to Administration -> Issues -> Workflows and click edit in the project related workflow.
2. This will open graphical view of the issue workflow.
3. You can add new status "Declined"
4. Publish the workflow.

this configuration will be applicable to this project only. It will allow filtering user story by status "not Declined".

Comment: I decided to add only the new "closed" status instead of changing the whole workflow. Switching to the classic workflow would be nice, because in the simple workflow I cannot select a resolution, but that's ok for us. Switching the whole workflow requires a bigger migration as well. Thanks for your help at all!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a different workflow. I noticed that lately the default workflow in JIRA is a simple one with only 3 statusses:

TODO -> IN PROGRESS -> DONE

In older versions of JIRA, the default workflow was a lot more complicated (but also a lot more useful IMO). An issue could be moved to a 'Closed' state with a "Won't Fix" reason.

Look for "classic default workflow" in the Workflow settings of your JIRA instance.

Comment: thank you for the hint, we will try it :)

Comment: Just to add that you can create a custom resolution. For example, you could create a resolution called 'declined' and use that when closing the issues.